# finding distance between synsets in wordnet

Tags: java, semantics, similarity, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

I use Java API for wordnet searching(JAWS) for accessing wordnet from java . When i got to read a few papers about semantic similarity with java , they expect me to find the distance between two synsets (is a relationship is used in building the hierarchy). There is no specific method to find the distance between words in JAWS .

Please tell me if there exists some method in java that gives the distance between two words

```
Example 

apple -> fruit-> fruits and vegetables (2) 
vegetables -> fruits and vegetables (1)
distance(apple,vegetable) = 3
```

Is there a built in method that performs this function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordnet Similarity in Java: JAWS, JWNL or Java WN::Similarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976537/wordnet-similarity-in-java-jaws-jwnl-or-java-wnsimilarity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there isn't using only JAWS, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394708/331719) gives a solution.

Comment: Thanks . But it gives the similarity between two words . I just want the distance between the two terms

Comment: Technically a similarity measure _is_ a distance measure: the smaller the similarity the larger the distance between the two words. If you mean by distance the number of edges to a common root, then you will have to count them. The similarity measure Wu & Palmer (1994) that is available in the linked API does just that: you could check its source code or just use the similarity it gives as a measure of your distance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use rita wordnet for that : 
http://rednoise.org/rita/reference/RiWordNet/getDistance/