# Why does Java Wordnet similarity crash on second call?

Tags: java, similarity, wordnet

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394708/1115059) I use the Java version of Wordnet::similarity.

This is the server side code. I recieve a List with two elements (i.e. two sentences)
and then compute the similarity matrix for those two sentences

```
String wordNetDirectory = System.getenv("WNHOME");
JWS ws = new JWS(wordNetDirectory,"3.0");
Resnik res = ws.getResnik();
while(true) {
    try {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Socket Established...");

        ObjectOutputStream outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        List<List<String>> sents;
        sents = (List<List<String>>) inFromClient.readObject();
        System.out.println("recieved");

        List<String> s1 = sents.get(0);
        List<String> s2 = sents.get(1);

        Double sum = 0.0;
        for(String w1 : s1) {
            for(String w2 : s2) {
                if(w1.equals(w2)) sum += 1;
                else sum += res.max(w1, w2, "n"); // <- Server.java:54
            }
        }
        sum /= (s1.size() * s2.size());
        outToClient.writeObject(sum);
        System.out.println("wrote " + sum);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }
}
```

The client queries the server for sentence similarity in a serial way (i.e. it sends another request after the similarity score of the previous pair is recieved)

**Here's the output I get on server side**

```
Socket Established...
recieved
wrote 0.111357828694864
Socket Established...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at edu.mit.jwi.item.IndexWordID.<init>(IndexWordID.java:62)
at edu.mit.jwi.CachingDictionary.getIndexWord(CachingDictionary.java:173)
at edu.sussex.nlp.jws.Resnik.res(Resnik.java:133)
at edu.sussex.nlp.jws.Resnik.max(Resnik.java:313)
at Server.start(Server.java:54)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

I don't understand why it crashes when connection is established for the second time.

Comment: As far as I know, it may because `w1` or `w2` is empty or all whitespace or does not appear in wordnet word list. You could change the string you put to have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may caused by a illegal word. If `w1` or `w2` is empty or all whitespace or does not appear in wordnet word list, you will get this exception when you fetch the wordID.

You get the exception in IndexWordID class, so I think this is the most possible problem. You could change the string you put to have a try, or give the code and string argument where you call the method for more information. You can see this doc http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/api/edu/mit/jwi/item/IndexWordID.html