# Find semantically similar word for natural language processing

Tags: nlp, semantics, similarity, words

I am working on a natural language processing project in Java. I have a requirement where I want to identify words that belong to similar semantic groups. 
e.g. : if the words such as `study` , `university`, `graduate` , `attend` are found I want them to be categorized as being related to education.
If words such as `golfer`, `batsman`, `athlete` are found, it should categorize all under a parent like sportsperson.
Is there a way I can achieve this task without using and training approach. Is there some toll like WordNet that can be used directly? Any pointer would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanx cheers!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use WordNet. For example, you can search among hypernyms of the current word (e.g. `study`) for your category word (e.g. `education` or `sport`). There are [JAWS](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html), [JWNL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet), and other libraries, see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976537/wordnet-similarity-in-java-jaws-jwnl-or-java-wnsimilarity).

Alternatively, you can compute similarity between candidate words and category words - e.g. by using [ws4j](https://code.google.com/p/ws4j/) or [Semilar](http://deeptutor2.memphis.edu/Semilar-Web/public/semilar-api.html).

Comment: WordNet hypernyms does give a similarity among the word I need. I'll try to read 
the text to derive a connection between each word. Thank you! Cheers!

Comment: I tried to find a way to do this using WordNet but I really couldn't find a way around. I tried using https://code.google.com/p/ws4j/ but that doesn't give consistent results. Pls help me!

Comment: I think you should create a new question (more concrete than this one) and describe there your steps, actual results, and expected results. Currently I don't have enough info for understanding what your problem is.