# Sentence correction using NLP

Tags: nlp, sentence-similarity

I'm trying to build a chat assistant in my website and it should answer queries like "Can you track my order?", "How's performance of XXX". The majority of the work lies in understanding the user's query.

I'm using 'Named Entity Recognizers' and "Text Parsers" for processing the queries. Before this, I'm passing the query through 'Spell checker' to reduce the errors like,

```
Can you track my ordr?
```

to

```
Can you track my order?
```

It's working in most of the cases but failing in cases like,

```
Can you track my water?
```

In this case, the spelling corrector doesn't correct the word 'water' and NER is not able identify the entity as 'order'.

The problem is 'Can you track my water?' may be a correct sentence in some other context but it's definitely a mistake in my context (domain). So I should be able to correct this sentence.

I'm stuck here.

Is there anyway I can correct these sentences using predefined queries and/or statistical data of user entered queries?

Comment: If you have a very specific domain, you can just create a set of "accepted words" to test for membership. But perhaps it is better to make it clear to the user that "water" makes no sense?

Comment: 'Water' may be an accepted word in some other sentence, ex. 'Is this phone water resistant?'. But it's not correct in this particular sentence. So following your idea, maybe I should define vocabulary for each kind of sentence..? If so, how would I do that.?

Comment: I would honestly reccommend NOT autocorrecting words that are "correct". Of course you could use a probabilistic model that suggests certain words that may be uncommon in a certain context "bigrams" / "n-grams" but I think you are overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way you can change "water" to "order".

But if you have a predefined set of questions then you may give the user suggestions to select from, just before he submits the question.

NER may only recognize/classify entities it may not be used to replace parts of sentences, because the user may have intended what he said.
What you do is suggest most probabilistic word based on your set.

References:

[What is the best way to find the most similar sentence?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-most-similar-sentence)

[Find semantically similar word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571927/find-semantically-similar-word-for-natural-language-processing)

Answer (score 1):

You could use *n-gram* models to find the most probable word and then use substitution. In your case, you substitute the word *ordr* by the word *order*. And if you want to go deeper you could use a machine learning model to handle the issue.